# How can I know the position of an element in an array? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    fin>>x[i];
    if(nrMax<x[i]){
        nrMax=x[i];
    }

}
```

How can I know the position of `nrMax` in array?

Comment: Just remember it in additional variable the same way you remember `nrMax`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve overall?

Comment: What if there are several elements with value nrMax? Do you need the first position of element with value nrMax or last position of such an element or list of the indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the index in a variable.

```
if (n > 0) {
    nrMaxIndex = 0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        fin>>x[i];
        if(x[nrMaxIndex] < x[i]){
            nrMaxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    nrMax = x[nrMaxIndex];
}
// else handle n==0 situation
```

Comment: Edited: Added a safety `if` around the code, otherwise the last statement would access `x[0]` even though it would be uninitialized.

Answer (score 2):

If you just store nrMax, you can search for an element with that value using `std::find`, but in the case you show, you should extend the inner conditional block to also store the current value of `i` into a variable like `idxMax`.